# How to retrieve client secret from the consumerKey(Client Name) in openAM

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openam

Is there is an endpoint in openAM which I can use to retrieve the client secret from the OpenAM.

I'm using the OpenAM as the keymanager and I have used the below endpoint with parameters to create an application in OpenAM

http://localhost:8080/openam/frrest/oauth2/client/?_action=create

Now I need to retrieve back the client secret using client name as I don't store it in my application side. What is the endpoint I need to use for it? I couldn't find it in the OpenAM documentation.

If OpenAM is not allowing to retrieve the client secret with the Client Name, what is the best way to handle this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Client secret is stored in hashed form that is irreversible in the OpenAM configuration store and cannot be retrieved.

Comment: So don't they have the DCRM support ?

Comment: Ah, my answer may be incorrect. Please wait a while.

Comment: You can send an OIDC client read request as follows: `# curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer [access token]' http://openam.example.com/openam/oauth2/connect/register?client_id=yourCilentId` but client secret is not included in the response if I remember correctly.